# Can you infer constraints to a single view?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Infer constraints is a nice option, but it gives constraints to ALL the views. I wonder if there is an option to infer constraints to a single view that you have selected.

Comment: Yes, click on that view and click on "Infer constraints" from the preview of the xml layout.

Comment: @IshtdeepHora what do you mean by "preview of xml layout"? There is the `text` tab, and the attributes tab, both without what you say.

Comment: The preview tab on the right side of xml

Comment: I have entered the text tab, clicked the preview tab, selected one view (in this case a layout) and clicked "infer constraints" and still all other views and layouts are affected. @IshtdeepHora